# Bit Shifting Confusion

Tags: c, bit

Why `0x56 << 2` is not  equal to `0x58`?

`0x56` is  `0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0`  so shifting 2 bits to the left we get

```
         0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

`01011000` is `0x58`. But its not the correct answer its `0x158`.So what am i missing here?

Even if i do this:

```
int main(){
    unsigned char a;
    a=0x56;
    printf("%x",a<<2);  // I am expecting the output to be 58 here.
}
```

Why its printing 158. **Why arent the only 8 bits considered?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bit shift operators `<<` and `>>` only work on integers. So when you use it here, they are first promoted to `int` (which is greater than 1 byte) and then the shift is done. You can see that it is mentioned in the standard at [6.5.7p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3)

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

`printf` (with `%x` and format specifier) also expects the argument to be of type `unsigned int`. So there is no demotion performed and you get `0x158`.

If you want the result to be only one byte, you should cast the result back to `unsigned char` as -

```
printf("%x", (unsigned char)(a << 2));
```

or you can declare another variable `b` and print that -

```
unsigned char b;   
b = a << 2;
printf("%x", b);
```

You can see the Demo [here](https://ideone.com/QYVfmZ).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I agree, but I think OP is wondering why he is getting more bits when he has declared `a` to be single byte wide. So the confusion is regarding types. I think he understands that masking higher bits would give the desired result too. That is my interpretation of the question and hence I focused only on the type aspect.

Comment: @M.M I meant that the expected argument is of type `int`, I will try to rephrase that part.

Comment: Do not forget the `hh` size specifier in printf or it will read `sizeof int` bytes from the stack while you only pushed `sizeof char`.

Comment: @BenjaminT I am sorry but I do not agree, default integer promotions are performed on all arguments to `printf` and the entire `4/8` bytes value shall be passed. Using `%hhx` deviates from OPs code and might lead to the confusion that, it is what lead to just a single byte being printed.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya My bad, I forgot about the promotion in printf().

Answer (score 2):

**C11 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**

Paragraph 2:

> Each of the operands shall have **integer** type.

Paragraph 3:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
>   of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of
>   the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width
>   of the promoted left operand, the behaviour is undefined.

So, we need both operands `int` type due to integer promotion.

Answer (score 2):

From [C Standards#6.5.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

So when you do this:

```
a<<2;
```

`a` is promoted to integer and then the shift operation is done. In `printf()` you are using `%x` format specifier which output the unsigned hexadecimal integer and hence you are getting output as `158`.